# CI4 accessing $data in the view

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have the following lines in my controller;

```
$this->data['user_time_zone']['user_setting_value'] = 'UTC';
return view('/User_private/Timezone/timezone_update', $this->data);
```

In my view, I really want to access the UTC var like this;

```
$user_time_zone->user_setting_value
```

How can I rewrite the controller part please?  I tried;

```
$this->data['user_time_zone']->user_setting_value = 'UTC'
```

but it complains of a non-object.

Answer (score 0):

This is solution

In controller function:

```
$this->data['user_time_zone']['user_setting_value'] = 'UTC';
$data['utc'] = $this->data['user_time_zone']['user_setting_value'];
return view('/User_private/Timezone/timezone_update', $data);
```

In view:

```
<?= $utc ?> or <?php echo $utc; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks but do not want to change the view.  Need to change the controller to match existing view. Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Let's work backwards and see what comes out.

If you need to use something like this in your view...

```
<?= 'The timezone is '.$user_time_zone->user_setting_value;?>
```

That means you will need an **object** called **$user_time_zone**.
(Items accessed with -> implies an object)

So to create that in your controller, you would need something like...

**Note:** I am assumming that the original object is called **$user_time_zone**

```
$user_time_zone->user_setting_value = 'UTC'; // Assign value to the object
$data['user_time_zone'] = $user_time_zone; // Assign the object to the view array.
```

**For testing, I created a controller with an index method like...**

```
public function index()
{
    $user_time_zone = (object)['user_setting_value' =>'']; // Create the Object for testing
    $user_time_zone->user_setting_value = 'UTC'; // Assign value to the object
    $data['user_time_zone'] = $user_time_zone; //Assign the object to the view array.

    return view('page_view', $data);
}
```

With the View (page_view.php) as

```
<?= 'The timezone is '.$user_time_zone->user_setting_value;?>
```

The takeaway from this is that **$data['user_time_zone']** needs to be an object with the property of **user_setting_value**

I hope that helps. If it's still not clear, just shout.